# Applying word reordering rules to a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, cpu-word

Let's assume we have:

```
[('The', 'DET'),
 ('red', 'ADJ'),
 ('window', 'NOUN'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('closed', 'VERB'),
 ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

It is a list of tuples such that their first element is a word of a sentence (in this case, 'The red window is closed.'), and the second its grammatical category (or tag).

Suppose we have the following rule:

1.)

```
  [('ADJ', 'NOUN'), ('NOUN', 'ADJ')]
```

This says that if we have an ADJ immediately followed by a NOUN (in this example, 'red', and 'window'), we should reorder them so that the NOUN is immediately followed by the ADJ.
The result of applying rule 1 to the sentence would then be:

```
[('The', 'DET'),
 ('window', 'NOUN'),
 ('red', 'ADJ'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('closed', 'VERB'),
 ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

Any one has an idea of how to automatize this for any number of other rules and sentences?
Or even just some basic strategy would help, really.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

Step 1: Set up variables (Here the rule you mentioned can be simplified)

```
sentence = [('The', 'DET'), ('red', 'ADJ'), ('window', 'NOUN'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('closed', 'VERB'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
rule = [('ADJ', 'NOUN')]
```

Step 2: Iterate over the items in your sentence

```
for index in range(0, len(sentence)):
```

Step 3: Get specific information from the tuples

```
current = sentence[index][1]
next = sentence[index+1][1]
```

Step 4: Compare

```
if current == rule[0][0] and next == rule[0][1]:
    print("Here we go, swapping!")
```

Naturally, this implementation is incomplete as there would be no point in me writing entire thing by myself.
A few notes:

- Remember to handle index+1 going out of bounds
- Switching 2 items might result in chained switches - say the order was ADJ, NOUN, NOUN, this will result in NOUN, ADJ, NOUN in first iteration, and NOUN, NOUN, ADJ in second one
- Complicated rules might break the idea of going for automatised behaviour

Comment: I hadn't thought of such a simple solution, thanks. 

One question, though, are you saying that if I had rules with a length higher than two, the strategy would be to apply the reordering by subsets of the rule of length 2?

Comment: @HillFarmer, I believe that would be the simplest approach, you would need an additional algorithm on how to break big rules into small rules (aka extract subsets from your rule set). Perhaps some sort of recursion, or a smart while loop would do the job? You could also break it into 2 additional, separate from each other steps - finding a pattern that matches a rule, and once you know it's in your sentence, doing the swaps. This should be easier than doing both at the same time.